# image opacity from 0 to 1 with css

Tags: css, image, opacity

I want my images to look like following:

The bottom part of the image is transparent, and to the top its getting to opacity 1.
I can do this effect with a color, with linear gradient:

```
-webkit-linear-gradient(black, transparent);
```

But is it possible with images too?

Comment: what's behind the image?

Comment: Use a static PNG with transparency, or do you need it to be animated?

Comment: Nothing a bit a javascript and a canvas wont fix.

Comment: hmm yes i could use just a normal image for this. But its interesting to now how to reach this with css or whatever, and maybe i want to animate it yes ;)

Behind the image is the background image from the body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newest and coolest way I know is using HTML 5 mask.

It goes like this:

**CSS:**

```
.masked
{
    mask: url(#m1); 
}
```

**HTML 5:**

```
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0" y1="0" x2 ="0" y2="100%">
      <stop stop-color="white" offset="0"/>
      <stop stop-color="black" offset="1"/>
    </linearGradient>

    <mask id="masking" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <rect y="0.1" width="1" height="0.9" fill="url(#gradient)" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
</svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="500" height="350">
    <image xlink:href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4d/Iss007e10807_darker.jpg"
           width="500" height="350" class="masked"></image>
</svg>
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gRZV9/10/)

---

For further reading:

- [Applying SVG effects to HTML content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Applying_SVG_effects_to_HTML_content) ([Live example](https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/2666/maskdemo.xhtml))
- [CSS Masking](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/)
- [Create Vector Masks using the HTML5 Canvas](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-vector-masks-using-the-html5-canvas)

Comment: Wow thank you first. But now i have to remove every line to look what it does, and how it works. ^^

Comment: It's just an example. Take 10 minutes to read about it and see the live example. It's not that complex.

Comment: Oh i see you just posted the example from the website sry

Comment: Very nice, another smart solution!

Comment: hm thank you but its not working. Is Chrome able to do that? Wait ill try in ie. EDIT: no he isnt doing it to :(

Comment: Could you take a screenshot of that?

Comment: Ouu yes thank you! But why the first variant isnt working in chrome? 
Now i have to write the code twice for cross browser support?

Comment: @T_01 Use the last fiddle I've posted, I've tested it on FF23, IE10, Chrome 29 and Opera 12.16

Comment: Yes its right. But im not understandig hoe it works... ive read the pages you postet but anyway... hmm

Comment: Look at the tags inside the svgs. We're defining a rectangle mask and then link it to a linear gradient. Then We're connecting it with an image. There's a lot of neccessary syntax there also

Answer (score 0):

My attempts with CSS :)

Codepen example: http://cdpn.io/hzBav

**CSS (Update with fadeout)**

```
figure {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  display: block;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;

  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 85%
  );
}

.overlay:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;

  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
  rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 100%
  );
}
```

**HTML**

```
<figure>
  <div class='overlay'></div>
  <img src='http://placekitten.com/300/300' />
</figure>
```

**Update based on comments.**

Comment: It's nice but the image won't get transparent

Comment: Yes i already thought at this, but the problem is you can just "fade it out", for example if you have an black background you can use this method. But its not solving the real problem.

Comment: I have updated but it's not very successful because now you can barely see the image, haha!